# Wildcard search using the python yum API

Tags: python, wildcard, yum

I'm trying to query yum using the python yum API to see if a package is installed or not. When I do this using the wildcard search (*) it doesn't work and says the package is not installed even if it is. If I type in the full-name of the package it works successfully.

I've tried to find another way to do a wildcard search but googling has yielded nothing of value.

I am attaching the relevant code snippet. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
import os
import sys
import yum
#imported yum stuff

yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.setCacheDir()
prereqs = "emr-*"
if yb.rpmdb.searchNevra(name=prereqs):
    okay = prereqs + " is already installed"
    print(okay)
else:
    nokay = prereqs + " is not installed"
    print(nokay)
```